# WordPress styling does not display without clearing cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, stylesheet

I am building a WordPress website with an Underscore theme, it is hosted on flywheel. Everytime I make changes to a page, the styling `style.css` file is not picked up unless I do a hard reload/ clear cache.

Obviously I want it to load on everyone's computer immediately without the need to clear the cache. What is the reason for this? and how can I resolve it?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins installed?

Comment: I don't is that why it's happening?

Comment: We'll if you don't have any installed, I highly doubt thats whats causing the issue.

Comment: Is the site live?

Comment: Right, it would make sense if that would happen if I WAS caching, but I am currently not. which is why it's weird...

Comment: @AlexThomas unfortunately not, but I have pushed it live, is weird because on some devices it appears normally, and on other devices it doesn't apply style.css without a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

You must change your theme version every time you make change in your style.css file. version will be appended to the URL as the query string. A version identifier is used to cache-bust the URL. The browser will detect the URL – with the query string – as a new and updated file rather than a cached resource.

see [WordPress Theme CSS and JS Cache Busting](https://wordimpress.com/wordpress-css-and-js-cache-busting/)